# use AWS vpn as default route

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, amazon-web-services

I have a VPN connection to AWS which works fine.  This is a site to site VPN.  I can route local subnets from AWS to the office and from the office to AWS.  What I am trying to accomplish now is to send all internet traffic out AWS.

I have put static default routes on my router and all internet traffic is hitting AWS.  Just not sure how to setup AWS for this.   I only see options on the NAT Gateway to allow local AWS subnets, I don't see an option to add other networks.  The routing table is fine cause again I am able to access local AWS resources.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Site to site VPN is intended to allow you to access resources in the VPC -- not beyond it.  You are correct in assuming that a NAT Gateway would be what you want, except that it wasn't designed to work this way.

> You cannot route traffic to a NAT gateway through a VPC peering connection, a Site-to-Site VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect. A NAT gateway cannot be used by resources on the other side of these connections.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

A route table entry pointing to your VPN is needed for instances to be reachable across the VPN, but your VPC route tables only apply to packets originating inside the VPC.  There is no route table -- including the default one for the VPC -- that is applied to packets originating on the outside end of the VPN.  VPN inbound packets implicitly route to all VPC subnets.

Comment: So instead of a NAT Gateway, is there a way to accomplish this?  I would like to route my office traffic through AWS for internet.  What are my options??